# Site menu not displaying some content in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you visit this website http://www.togethermutualinsurance.co.uk in any browser apart from safari (in windows) the menu displays fine.

However when I visit this website in safari it does not display the title of the menus and and submenus with images.

I have tried everything in css I just can't get my head around it.

Here is the menu css file

http://togethermutualinsurance.co.uk/TG/App_Stylesheets/Menu/mainmenu.css

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply  -

```
html,body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Web browsers have different default settings for the base margins and padding.

You need to set this to make sure your browsers are all set to equal levels for margin/padding.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to open the website in afari and found out the issue

check the image the issue is with  #main-menu li class reomve padding and margin and there your menu comes...

```
    #main-menu li 
{

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
margin:0, padding:0 in ul, li
```